# Excel Add-in - Delphi equivilent to VB

Tags: c#, delphi, excel, excel-addins, vba

I'm porting an Excel add-in from visual VB to Delphi 2006.  Most of it is working but I am stuck on these two VB lines:

```
oXL.Selection.QueryTable
oXL.Selection <> ""
```

where oXL is defined as Excel.Application.

In Delphi ExcelApplication.Selection requires an index but in VB it doesn't.  I couldn't find anything similar in C# either.  I have tried ExcelApplication.ActiveCell which works as long as there is an existing query, otherwise Excel crashes.

Does anyone know what this translates into for Delphi, or C#?

Also if oXL.Selection is an interface, how can you perform oXL.Selection <> ""?

Thank you.

Comment: `ExcelApplication.Selection requires an index`. You can look this up in the source for `ExcelApplication` and see that the index is a locale ID. It is also documented on MSDN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries, I had forgotten that you can just cast the application IDispatch interface to an OleVariant and then call the method.

But what I've done instead is just the following

```
try
  ExcelApplication.ActiveCell.QueryTable.Refresh(False);
except
end;
```

This seems to be the only way to make it work without crashing excel.

Comment: Strange. In theory _anything_ you call over IDispatch/OleVariant _should_ be available somewhere in the type library with a specific interface, though it sometimes takes you a long way round.

Answer (score 2):

When automating Excel from Delphi using interfaces, a lot of methods take a LCID. You can use `LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT` for that.

```
var
  oxlSelection: ExcelRange;

ExcelApplication.ActiveCell.QueryTable;
if Supports(fExcelApplication.Selection[LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT], ExcelRange, oxlSelection)
  and (VarToStr(oxlSelection.Text) <> '') then
begin
  //do something
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've run across this problem a lot of times, the solution is very simple.
Always use `0` for the localeID and everything will work as excepted.
This will make Excel fill in its default locale.

```
ExcelApplication.ActiveCell.QueryTable;
if OleVariant(ExcelApplication.Selection[0]).Value <> '' then .....
```

You can use variants and then you don't suffer this requirement, but in that case:

- your code will run slower (all that variant magic takes time)
- you will not have context help on your ExcelApplication methods and properties.

Note that `selection`, like `cells` returns a IDispatch, that you have to cast to a Olevariant, in order to work with it.
The same annoying thing happens in VBA, except there the cast is implicit.

Comment: ExcelApplication.Selection[LCID] returns an IDispatch, this interface does not have a `Value`-property

Comment: Oh, I forget, `selection`, like `cells` is one of those annoying properties that returns a general OleVariant Object. It does the same in VBA. very annoying.